# Execise angularJS windows alert not woring

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've a simple problem, i've copied and pasted some code and i'd like to show an alert with a value inside it. I'm just learning angular and the fuction works (i've places a console log inside it and it is executed), but the window.alert doesn't appear.

I've read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) tutorial and tried changing the name of variable but it's still not working. In the [online tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) of angual everything is going fine so where is my mistake?

Here is the page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="greetings.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Greetings</h1>
<div ng-app="greetings" ng-controller="GreetingsController as greeting">
  <b>Greetings:</b>
  <div>
    Name: <input type="text" min="0" ng-model="greeting.name" required >
  </div>
  <div>
    FamilyName: <input type="text" ng-model="greeting.familyName" required >
    <select 
    data-ng-options="c for c in greeting.tipi" data-ng-model="greeting.selectedOption">
      <!--<option ng-repeat="c in greeting.tipi">{{c}}</option>-->
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Greeting:</b>
    <span>
      {{greeting.total(greeting.selectedOption)}} {{greeting.name}} {{greeting.familyName}}
      <button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.greet(greeting.selectedOption)">Greet</button>
      <br/>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller code greetings.js:

```
angular.module('greetings', [])
.controller('GreetingsController', function() {
  this.name = "Name";
  this.familyName = "FamilyName";
  this.tipi = ["Hello", "Good Morning", "Good Afternoon", "Good evening"];
  this.selectedOption = this.tipi[0];
  this.total = function total(outGree) {
      console.log(outGree);
      return outGree;
  };
  this.greet = function greet(outGree) {
      console.log(outGree);
      $window.alert(outGree);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
To use an Angular service, you add it as a dependency for the component (controller, service, filter or directive) that depends on the service.
And $window is a service.
```

you should add the parameter or the dependency **$window** to use this service.

```
angular.module('greetings', [])
.controller('GreetingsController', ['$window', function($window) {
  this.name = "Name";
  this.familyName = "FamilyName";
  this.tipi = ["Hello", "Good Morning", "Good Afternoon", "Good evening"];
  this.selectedOption = this.tipi[0];
  this.total = function total(outGree) {
      console.log(outGree);
      return outGree;
  };
  this.greet = function greet(outGree) {
      console.log(outGree);
      $window.alert(outGree);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: That javascript contains an error: Missing closing square bracket on the very last line !!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include $window in your dependencies, or else your controller reads it as undefined.

Try the following:

```
angular.module('greetings', [])
.controller('GreetingsController', function($window) {
  //Rest of your code

  this.greet = function greet(outGree) {
      console.log(outGree);
      $window.alert(outGree);
  };
});
```

I added $window as a parameter to the function of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was in the html code:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.greet(greeting.selectedOption)">Greet</button>
```

should have been:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="greeting.greet(greeting.selectedOption)">Greet</button>
```